# Publicação de site MVC 4 no IIS está dando erro

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, iis

Subi minha aplicação publicada para o IIS e não consigo ver no browser. Antes estava dando erro de Forbidden(403) e agora de Server Error(404). Eu nunca subi um site em MVC para o IIS. Sempre soube que não é da forma convencional, há algumas coisas a serem setadas e etc, mas confesso estou perdido, eu e meu colega que administra o IIS aqui na empresa.

Comment: O suporte a MVC foi instalado neste IIS?

Comment: Vou perguntar. Nem sabia disso. É algum framework para o IIS que deve ser instalado? Tem que baixar isso? Vou fazer uma pesquisa sobre onde conseguir, mas se alguém souber e puder me passar eu agradeço.

Answer (score 3):

Cara, é o seguinte, antes de qualquer coisa, instale o Web Plataform da Microsoft. Lá tem todos os aplicativos necessários pra se fazer o deploy de sua aplicação no IIS.
Ok, baixando e rodando o Web Plataform, antes de tudo, instale o IIS Express, que é o gratuito que é disponibilizado pra download. É simples, e vocês já fizeram isso.

Baixado o IIS e configurade os pools de aplicativo pra versão do Asp.Net instalado(v4.0).

- Aqui cabe uma dica, pra acessar o IIS vá em menu iniciar > executar > digite inetmgr, feito isso vai abrir o IIS, e verifique se sua aplicação está nele, provavelmente está retornando 404 porque não está no IIS sua aplicação.

Depois de instalado o IIS, instale o Web Deploy também

O que eu faço pra que minha aplicação funcione no IIS e rode: Dou o deploy pelo VS(e para isso você deve estar rodando ele em modo Administrador. Para isso clique com o botão direito no atalho do VS e escolha a opção "Executar como Administrador". Isso em PCs normais, pois em servers o VS roda em modo Administrador sempre).

Ok rodou o VS, abra seu projeto e clique com o botão direito e vá na opção "Publish". Ao clicar você deverá criar um perfil e escolher uma das opções disponíveis pra fazer o deploy no IIS e pronto, o VS faz tudo pra você.

Deu o deploy certinho, vá no navegador e digite na barra de endereços "localhost". Se o IIS estiver rodando sem problemas irá aparecer uma imagem que é um link pro site oficial do IIS da Microsoft. Ok, apareceu a imagem e tal, então digite na barra de endereços "localhost/nome_do_ projeto " e dê enter. Pronto seu projeto irá rodar tranquilamente.

Aqui não estou passando passos de instalação de Servidor de banco de dados, pois essa não é a pergunta ok ?

Comment: Vou testar e funcionando ou não eu volto a postar o resultado.

Comment: Tranquilo cara, é bom esse feedback. Teste ai e veja !

Answer (score 0):

Instale no servidor o suporte ao MVC:

> http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5

Comment: Não funcionou. O servidor é Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, meu servidor é Windows Server 2008 R2, sei como é sofrer para configurar..rsrs

1. O primeiro passo é instalar via [Microsoft Web Plataform](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) as configurações recomendadas para o IIS, veja neste tutorial como fazê-lo:
   [Installing and Configuring Web Deploy on IIS 7](http://www.iis.net/learn/install/installing-publishing-technologies/installing-and-configuring-web-deploy)
2. Instale no servidor a versão do .NetFrameWork da sua aplicação, para saber qual é a configuração, veja no seu webconfig qual é valor do atributo targetFramework:

```xml
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

3. Sua aplicação tem rodar em pool com pipeline integrado
4. recomendo que, inicialmente habilite o debug. deixe o customErros em modo off e mostre os erros detalhadamente, para isto basta adicionar a seguinte configuração no webconfig:

```xml
   <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
  </system.web>
```

O bom de usar os erros detalhados, é que que facilita a adequação do servidor à sua aplicação.

Espero ter ajudado..